# The failure policy problem between task nodes with dependent relationships

Tags: apache-dolphinscheduler

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkszD.png)

Now there is such a process composed of three task nodes, NO1, NO2 and NO3 just want to execute in the order shown in the figure, whether the intermediate task node succeeds or fails, the subsequent nodes will continue to execute, should not support such a function now?
Now, as long as one of the intermediate task nodes has failed status, subsequent tasks will not be executed.
Whether or not the community has such consideration, this scenario is also real.
The current failure policy is for parallel task nodes, not for the one line task nodes.

Answer (score 0):

if it belongs to a serial task (the picture depicts a serial task), then the result of the execution of the previous node is definitely affecting the subsequent node.

If you want to achieve the functionality you described, i.e. the results of the preceding and following nodes are not affected, then you can use a parallel task

Comment: At present, our real usage scenario requires tasks to be executed in sequence, and the success of previous tasks does not affect the success of subsequent tasks.     If it is changed to parallel tasks, when the process is started, the tasks will run at the same time, which does not meet the actual use requirements.    Would the community consider adding such a switch button